# "However difficult something is, …" or "However difficult something may/might be, …" ?

Tags: adverbs, modal-verbs

Does it make sense to follow an adjective phrase such as "however difficult" with the modal auxiliaries "may/might"? Isn't it a bit pleonastic, since "however" already contains the idea of either uncertainty, or irrelevance?

"**However wealthy he was / However wealthy he might have been**, she would not have married him if she had not been in love with him."

Does "he was" imply that his wealth was certain **but** irrelevant, and "he might have been", that it is/was a matter for conjecture **and** irrelevant, anyway?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, and yes to your last question, which gives a good account of the sense it makes.

Comment: To me, *however clever you are* more strongly implies that you're definitely "clever", even though it's contextually irrelevant exactly *how* clever you are. Whereas *however clever you **might be*** admits of the possibility that you might not actually be at all clever (not that it matters! :)